# H2 DB - Column must be in Group By list

Tags: java, sql, database, h2

i am using H2-DB to access static databases...

i have a table which looks like:

```
COUNTRY     STATE       CITY         LAT     LNG     COUNTRYID      STATEID     CITYID 
"Germany"   "Berlin"    ""           1.23    1.23    1              1           0
"Germany"   "München"   ""           1.23    1.23    1              2           0
"USA"       "Alabama"   "Auburn"     1.23    1.23    2              1           1
"USA"       "Alabama"   "Birmingham" 1.23    1.23    2              1           2
"USA"       "Alaska"    "Anchorage"  1.23    1.23    2              2           1
"USA"       "Alaska"    "Cordova"    1.23    1.23    2              2           2
```

its a huge list with lots of countries, most of them just have Country and State (like Germany here, whereas State's are Cities), a few also have a City (like USA here)...

the problem is now, when i query

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE COUNTRY = 'Germany' group by STATE order by STATE
```

to get a sorted list of the states (or cities), i get an error saying

```
Field CITY must be in the GROUP BY list
```

if the row has a city, i need the whole row, otherwise i would only need the State column, but i can just know after having queried it, wether it uses the city column or not, so i have to query "*" instead of "STATE"

the query should be okay, or? On MySql it is properly working... so whats the problem here?

Found this if it helps: http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/constant/ErrorCode.html#c90016

Metin

Comment: do you mean `SELECT STATE, CITY FROM DIYANET WHERE COUNTRY = 'Germany' ORDER BY STATE, CITY`

Comment: Please edit your question with your desired results.

Comment: If there is a city, I need "*" (would work, if there wouldn't be multiple empty city columns), if city is empty I do only need state... On mysql it is no problem, if there are multiple of one column (here they are always empty), it just gives one, I haven't to add that to group by...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQL is broken in regards to this.  It allows columns in the `GROUP BY` that are neither in the `group by` nor arguments to aggregation functions.  In fact, the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html) warns against using this extension.

So you can do:

```
SELECT state
FROM DIYANET
WHERE COUNTRY = 'Germany'
GROUP BY STATE 
ORDER BY STATE;
```

Or something like this:

```
SELECT state, min(city), min(lat), . . .
FROM DIYANET
WHERE COUNTRY = 'Germany'
GROUP BY STATE 
ORDER BY STATE;
```

But `SELECT *` is not allowed and doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Even if it nonsense, I need it :) but thank you, now I know the problem, why it is working on mysql and not on h2...I will add one query more, to fix it :)...

Comment: But if I execute MySQL query directly, MySQL returns 'CITY' column which appears first in each group. I just need this behavior. Why would Hibernate forbidden this?