# strange group by error occuring SOMETIMES

Tags: ignite

I "SOMETIMES" get the below exception on my server logs when executing the query. Query has a group by statement. If i remove the GROUP BY i never get the exception. Also not all queries with group by get the exception. Only some of them are victims.

I have two server in cluster and a client node.

Is there any problem with the query or am i hitting to a bug because the exception occurs randomly. The strange thing is that not all the queries got this exception. I think the query structure is OK.

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "PR__Z0._VAL" must be in the GROUP BY list; SQL statement: 
SELECT 
PR__Z0._VAL __C0_0, 
PR__Z0."dailyRock" __C0_1, 
PR__Z0."productId" __C0_2 
FROM TABLE("category" CHAR=?1) T__Z2 
 INNER JOIN ACC_6185BAEEDA626000."ProductCategory" PC__Z1 
 ON TRUE 
 INNER JOIN ACC_6185BAEEDA626000."ProductRecord" PR__Z0 
 ON TRUE 
WHERE (PC__Z1."language" = ?2) AND ((PC__Z1."category" = T__Z2."category") AND (PR__Z0."productId" = PC__Z1."productId")) 
GROUP BY PR__Z0."productId" 
ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT ?3 + ?4 [90016-197] 
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357) 
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179) 
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155) 
        at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.updateAggregate(ExpressionColumn.java:172) 
        at org.h2.expression.Alias.updateAggregate(Alias.java:87) 
        at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryGroup(Select.java:350) 
        at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryWithoutCache(Select.java:628) 
        at org.h2.command.dml.Query.queryWithoutCacheLazyCheck(Query.java:114) 
        at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:352) 
        at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:333) 
        at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:114) 
        at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:202) 
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:114) 
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.PreparedStatementExImpl.executeQuery(PreparedStatementExImpl.java:67) 
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.executeSqlQuery(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1421) 
        ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 0):

See [H2 DB - Column must be in Group By list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596497/h2-db-column-must-be-in-group-by-list).

Apache Ignite is strict in this sence where you are only allowed to put naked values in SELECT list that you also put in GROUP BY lisT:

`SELECT V1, V2, V3 FROM table GROUP BY V1, V2, V3` <-- if you remove either V1, V2 or V3 from GROUP BY == error

All other values need to be wrapped in an [aggregate function](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html).

As in `SELECT MAX(_VAL), AVG("dailyRock"), "productId" ... GROUP BY "productId";`